# fancontrol on no pw-capable machines

Tags: dell, cpu, overheating, fan, alienware

I've installed Ubuntu 13.4 on my Alienware m14x and noticed one thing, cpu gets as high as 70 degrees centigrade (with nothing resourceful running) and cooler doesn't respond to that, just stays calm and quiet. How can I change that?

`fancontrol` couldn't help me - `pwmconfig` says: "There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed"

upd: I've managed to control fan speed with `i8kutils`. By running `i8kctl fan 1 2` I've managed to speed it a bit, but I can't get to the highest possible speed. CPU still gets close to critical temps.

upd2: I think I've managed preventing the laptop from overheating by installing bumblebee, but still couldn't find a way to run the fan on its highest possible speed, so theoretically it still can get to critical temps. I'll be testing that.
Also apparently bumblebee installation removed i8kutils so no way to control the fan manually anymore.

Comment: Did you try fancontrol?

Comment: yes pwconfig reports that "There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed"

Comment: I am now voting to re-open your question. Could provide some more hardware information please? Thanks!

Comment: I don't agree with TomKat. I‘m facing same problem here. I can only use i8kctl to control my dell vostro 3560. But i8kctl only has 3 level of speed namely 0, 1, 2. When I set fan speed to 2 with command **i8kctl fan -1 2**, its speed is 135500. But if I don't use i8kctl, the fan speed can go to 144000, but you can never set fan to this speed with i8kctl command. I believe it's a problem of i8kctl which inherently has only low and high speed option. So we need to seek for another solution for our laptop.

Answer (score 3):

The marked 'maximum' speeds on fans are theoretical, and can be rarely reached practically. Something that 'may' help is: Open the chassis, take the fan out and clean it free from any dust in there. Make sure there's proper ventilation so that dust doesn't block the airflow.

Keep Bumblebee installed and let it control the fan speed.

Answer (score 0):

I have dell inspiron and I was not able to install AMD grahics drivers for my graphics card after installing 13.04 . 
  For some reasons unknown to me, the driver was not available and it was causing my laptop to goes off because of over heating.
 I suggest you to check if your graphics driver is properly installed and working properly otherwise to resolve this I have downgraded to 12.04.